# Unity3D - How to move objects in a Sine wave independantly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, trigonometry

In my game I have targets that spawn and move towards the player in a straight line. I use this code:

```
transform.LookAt(target.transform);
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, speed);
```

Which makes the target home in on the player and move towards them.

I decided to try and make them move in a sin wave, so it looks less boring than going in a straight line, and I added a line of code, which now becomes:

```
transform.LookAt(target.transform);
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, speed);
transform.position += transform.right * Mathf.Sin (Time.time * 3f) * 1f;
```

Now this works great, my enemies move left and right as they travel towards the player, except, they all follow the same path at the same time, resulting in a large group of targets moving left and right in a sort of choreographed way.

I believe it is because I use `Time.time` in the `Mathf.Sin` piece of code, which results in all the targets using the same value to generate a sine wave.

**I've tried** changing to `Time.deltaTime` and changing the `Time.time` variable to a `Random.Range` variable between 2 numbers, but they either don't work, stop my targets from moving, or make them look like they are vibrating. I've also tried using animations as well, but because of my `MoveTowards` code, this doesn't work either.

So, is there a way to make a `GameObject` move left and right in a sine wave and move forwards at the same time, but independently so they do not look choreographed? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to offset the phase of the sine function (while keeping the frequency and amplitude) you have to **add** a constant to x in sin(x).

So you could try `transform.position += transform.right * Mathf.Sin (Time.time * 3f + i) * 1f;` where **i** is unique to the target moving towards the player.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave